# PHP Post XML Request to server ( TNT Express Connect Pricing module)

Tags: php, xml, post

I try to make http post request to TNT Express connect pricing module service:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .= '<PRICEREQUEST>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<LOGIN>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .= '<COMPANY>xxxxx</COMPANY>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .= '<PASSWORD>xxxxx</PASSWORD>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .= '<APPID></APPID>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .= '</LOGIN>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .= '<DATASETS>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<COUNTRY>1.0</COUNTRY>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .= '<CURRENCY>1.0</CURRENCY>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .= '<POSTCODEMASK>1.0</POSTCODEMASK>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<TOWNGROUP>1.0</TOWNGROUP>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<SERVICE>1.0</SERVICE>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<OPTION>1.0</OPTION>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='</DATASETS>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<PRICECHECK>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<RATEID>rate1</RATEID>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<ORIGINCOUNTRY>GB</ORIGINCOUNTRY>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<ORIGINTOWNNAME></ORIGINTOWNNAME>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<ORIGINPOSTCODE></ORIGINPOSTCODE>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<ORIGINTOWNGROUP></ORIGINTOWNGROUP>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<DESTCOUNTRY>AU</DESTCOUNTRY>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<DESTTOWNNAME></DESTTOWNNAME>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<DESTPOSTCODE></DESTPOSTCODE>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<DESTTOWNGROUP></DESTTOWNGROUP>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<CONTYPE>D</CONTYPE>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<CURRENCY>GBP</CURRENCY>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='<WEIGHT>0.2</WEIGHT>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .= '<VOLUME>0</VOLUME>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .= '<ITEMS>1</ITEMS>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='</PRICECHECK>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml .='</PRICEREQUEST>';

$url = 'iconnection.tnt.com';
$lenght = strlen($xml)+7;
$headers = array(
                "POST PriceGate.asp HTTP/1.0",
                "Accept:*/*",
                "User-Agent: PriceGate_socket/1.0",
                "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Content-length: $lenght",
                );



$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 81);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$result =  curl_exec($ch); 

 if (empty($result)) {
   // some kind of an error happened
    die(curl_error($ch));
      curl_close($ch); // close cURL handler
   } else {
      $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
      curl_close($ch); // close cURL handler

      if (empty($info['http_code'])) {
              die("No HTTP code was returned");
      } else {
//       

       // echo results
          echo "The server responded: \n";
          echo $info['http_code'];
      }
   }


   echo '<pre>';
   print_r ($result); 
   echo '</pre>';
```

But got response: couldn't connect to host

What i doing wrong?
Mayby there is some another solution to interact tnt services or get some debug information?
Many thanks

**UPDATE**

Now response is:

```
The server responded: 405

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD
Content-Length: 1564
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 11 Sep 2013 10:12:01 GMT
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is my new php code: http://pastebin.com/a4s4yLLu

- Changed: address: https://express.tnt.com/expressconnect/pricing/getprice
- Comment curl headers

Now i got response: `Fatal error: Curl failed with error #7: couldn't connect to host in /home/client/public_html/tnt/test3.php on line 104`

Comment: -> ***couldn't connect to host*** <- double check host and port. start connecting to host with a very simple request, I suggest to try this out with curl on the commandline.

Comment: What now? See my update

Comment: Now -> ***Method Not Allowed*** (405), that means (in this case), you can only send a OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD but not a POST request (as you do). You should probably find out where the documentation of that webservice is. As each webservice is indidvidual it is normally needed to give you better suggestions how to continue.

Comment: Here is documentation: https://express.tnt.com/expresswebservices-website/docs/ExpressConnect%20Pricing%20Integration%20Guide.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whilst this may be 30 days late.. I've actually been assigned the same project.. x) But took me a while to tinker around with it..

```
<?php
    /**
     *  Submit XML to the TNT
     *  server via a Stream instead
     *  of cURL. 
     *
     *  @Returns String (XML)
    **/
    function sendToTNTServer( $Xml ) {

    $postdata = http_build_query(
                       array(
                         //For Future reference
                         //the xml_in= ( the = ) is appended
                         //Automatically by PHP
                        'xml_in' => $Xml 
                       )
            );

    $opts = array('http' =>
                array(
                   'method'  => 'POST',
                   'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                   'content' => $postdata
                 )
             );

    $context  = stream_context_create( $opts );
    $output = file_get_contents( 
           'https://express.tnt.com/expressconnect/pricing/getprice', 
           false, 
           $context 
         );

         return $output;
    }

    $XmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> 
                  <PRICEREQUEST> 
                       <LOGIN> 
                           <COMPANY>YOUR USERID</COMPANY> 
                           <PASSWORD>YOUR PASSWORD</PASSWORD> 
                           <APPID>PC</APPID> 
                       </LOGIN> 
                       <PRICECHECK> 
                           <RATEID>rate1</RATEID> 
                           <ORIGINCOUNTRY>GB</ORIGINCOUNTRY> 
                           <ORIGINTOWNNAME>Atherstone</ORIGINTOWNNAME> 
                           <ORIGINPOSTCODE>CV9 2RY</ORIGINPOSTCODE> 
                           <ORIGINTOWNGROUP/> 
                           <DESTCOUNTRY>ES</DESTCOUNTRY> 
                           <DESTTOWNNAME>Alicante</DESTTOWNNAME> 
                           <DESTPOSTCODE>03006</DESTPOSTCODE> 
                           <DESTTOWNGROUP/> 
                           <CONTYPE>N</CONTYPE> 
                           <CURRENCY>GBP</CURRENCY> 
                           <WEIGHT>0.2</WEIGHT> 
                           <VOLUME>0.1</VOLUME> 
                           <ACCOUNT/> 
                           <ITEMS>1</ITEMS> 
                     </PRICECHECK> 
                </PRICEREQUEST>";

    $returnXml = sendToTNTServer( $XmlString );
    echo $returnXml;
?>
```

Comment: Morning, I do! I'll have to change the entire answer soon =)

Comment: @KārlisMillers have a try with the above.. I know it's very different =)

Comment: OMG ! YOU DID IT :) GOT Response: UTDUTDUTDUTDUTDP13RATEID: rate1 - Standard Ratesrate115NExpressNONEGBP239.56Yrate115NExpressPriorityGBP264.56Yrate148NEconomy ExpressNONEGBP112.42Y

Comment: Awesome ;) I have to say, yesterday I decided to start again as `cURL` kept having so __many__ problems, still to this day I don't know why. The original code I had actually wasn't POSTing, it was still GETing, as I didn't have `CURL_SETOPT( POST, 1 )`. which retrieved the information I didn't need. I had found a couple of comments about `stream_context_create()` that seemed to work with TNT just fine, and also I didn't realise adding `xml_in=` (with `=` ) was actually being read as: `xml_in==` AND! Ironic isn't it? We didn't even need to set even any content length or custom headers... . TNT!

Comment: I try to connect with the above give answer code for my project, but still I get **login details not recognised**

Comment: @doubleD You were supplied a username/password by TNT directly?

Comment: @mike_x_ The ExpressConnect system generally depends on the Town field not being blank unfortunately! It's probably the second most important field after the Postcode for their internal database queries.

Comment: Finally it worked by leaving it blank. I have no idea what a town group is..is it a term of TNT?how can i know the destination towngroup? Also, what is the default weight and volume units of measure?

Comment: In my case, Different country working fine. But domestic(Australia) not working. @MackieeE

Comment: How can we book consignment ?

Comment: Thanks Mackiee, but how do you phrase the output?