# TNT Express Connect Pricing module Using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I need to connect to the TNT Expressconnect and get pricing details for given weight and volume of products I am using PHP and try to connect with this lines of codes which is in [PHP Post XML Request to server ( TNT Express Connect Pricing module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719502/php-post-xml-request-to-server-tnt-express-connect-pricing-module?answertab=active)

```
<?php
/**
 *  Submit XML to the TNT
 *  server via a Stream instead
 *  of cURL. 
 *
 *  @Returns String (XML)
**/

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function sendToTNTServer( $Xml ) {

$postdata = http_build_query(
                   array(
                     //For Future reference
                     //the xml_in= ( the = ) is appended
                     //Automatically by PHP
                    'xml_in' => $Xml 
                   )
        );

$opts = array('http' =>
            array(
               'method'  => 'POST',
               'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               'content' => $postdata
             )
         );

$context  = stream_context_create( $opts );
$output = file_get_contents( 
       'https://express.tnt.com/expressconnect/pricing/getprice', 
       false, 
       $context 
     );

     return $output;
}

$XmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> 
              <PRICEREQUEST> 
                   <LOGIN> 
                       <COMPANY>CITXXXXXX</COMPANY> 
                       <PASSWORD>XXXXX</PASSWORD> 
                       <APPID>PC</APPID> 
                   </LOGIN> 
                   <PRICECHECK> 
                       <RATEID>rate1</RATEID> 
                       <ORIGINCOUNTRY>AUD</ORIGINCOUNTRY> 
                       <ORIGINTOWNNAME>Atherstone</ORIGINTOWNNAME> 
                       <ORIGINPOSTCODE>CV9 2RY</ORIGINPOSTCODE> 
                       <ORIGINTOWNGROUP/> 
                       <DESTCOUNTRY>ES</DESTCOUNTRY> 
                       <DESTTOWNNAME>Alicante</DESTTOWNNAME> 
                       <DESTPOSTCODE>03006</DESTPOSTCODE> 
                       <DESTTOWNGROUP/> 
                       <CONTYPE>N</CONTYPE> 
                       <CURRENCY>GBP</CURRENCY> 
                       <WEIGHT>0.2</WEIGHT> 
                       <VOLUME>0.1</VOLUME> 
                       <ACCOUNT/> 
                       <ITEMS>1</ITEMS> 
                 </PRICECHECK> 
            </PRICEREQUEST>";

$returnXml = sendToTNTServer( $XmlString );
    echo $returnXml;
?>
```

but this code give me an error of **login details not recognised**

Answer (score 1):

check the code :: change `<ORIGINCOUNTRY>` value `AUD` to `AU`

```
             <PRICECHECK> 
                   <RATEID>rate1</RATEID> 
                   <ORIGINCOUNTRY>AU</ORIGINCOUNTRY> 
                   <ORIGINTOWNNAME>Atherstone</ORIGINTOWNNAME> 
                   <ORIGINPOSTCODE>CV9 2RY</ORIGINPOSTCODE> 
                   <ORIGINTOWNGROUP/> 
                   <DESTCOUNTRY>ES</DESTCOUNTRY> 
                   <DESTTOWNNAME>Alicante</DESTTOWNNAME> 
                   <DESTPOSTCODE>03006</DESTPOSTCODE> 
                   <DESTTOWNGROUP/> 
                   <CONTYPE>N</CONTYPE> 
                   <CURRENCY>AUD</CURRENCY> 
                   <WEIGHT>0.2</WEIGHT> 
                   <VOLUME>0.1</VOLUME> 
                   <ACCOUNT/> 
                   <ITEMS>1</ITEMS> 
             </PRICECHECK>
```

Answer (score -1):

I know I'm a little late on this one, but I have spent all this time digging into this issue and at this point I might I have found the answer. Although I might be wrong, I think that they can't recognize your login details. I know that it might sound crazy, but if we look closer into what was in their response and apply a little bit of logic here and there, it might be the issue here. Hope this will help you and others who came here from google, looking for issues with TNT API. Have a nice day.