# How PHP Post XML Request to server ( TNT Express Connect Pricing module) using appVersion 3.2?

Tags: php, express, module

In this post  [TNT Express Connect Pricing module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719502/php-post-xml-request-to-server-tnt-express-connect-pricing-module), [@MackieeE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/292735/mackieee) show a valid solution for 2.0 version of the TNT API. I'm trying use 3.2 version and it doesn't work

I'm usign this values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<priceRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <appId>PC</appId>
  <appVersion>3.2</appVersion>
  <priceCheck>
    <rateId>rate2</rateId>
    <sender>
      <country>ES</country>
      <town>BENISSA</town>
      <postcode>03720</postcode>
    </sender>
    <delivery>
      <country>ES</country>
      <town>TORREFARRERA</town>
      <postcode>25123</postcode>
    </delivery>
    <collectionDateTime>2019-05-07T11:10:00</collectionDateTime>
    <product>
      <id>15N</id>
      <type>N</type>
    </product>
    <account>
      <accountNumber>YOUR ACCOUNT NUMBER</accountNumber>
      <accountCountry>ES</accountCountry>
    </account>
    <insurance>
      <insuranceValue>110.00</insuranceValue>
      <goodsValue>100.00</goodsValue>
    </insurance>
    <currency>EUR</currency>
    <priceBreakDown>true</priceBreakDown>
    <consignmentDetails>
      <totalWeight>1.25</totalWeight>
      <totalVolume>0.1</totalVolume>
      <totalNumberOfPieces>1</totalNumberOfPieces>
    </consignmentDetails>
    <pieceLine>
      <numberOfPieces>1</numberOfPieces>
      <pieceMeasurements>
        <length>1</length>
        <width>2</width>
        <height>3</height>
        <weight>1.25</weight>
      </pieceMeasurements>
      <pallet>1</pallet>
    </pieceLine>
  </priceCheck>
</priceRequest>
```

The response is:

Cannot find the declaration of element 'priceRequest'

in https://express.tnt.com/expresswebservices-website/app/pricingrequest.html works fine, but I need do it in my Php code.

Any help?  thanks

Comment: You're trying to use eight year old code written for a different version of the API. It's not surprising it doesn't work. Go to the API documentation and start from there.

Comment: It is true that the example was for API 2.0 and I want to use 3.2 (more current), however in the API documentation from TNT, they do not give support or examples for Php in Pricing Module, in the Shipping part there is an example with curl but it does not work for me.

I was assuming you could use file_get_contents with version 3.2 instead of using curl.

My problem is that I can't get file_get_contents to work with version 3.2

Answer (score 1):

if you need to get the price use this api https://express.tnt.com/expressconnect/pricing/getprice
but im not sure if it will make the order. Also i had a problem with the respond in my php code. It turned out that TNT send back the XML file in a string.

simplexml_load_string($result)

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the link at the top of OP's question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30231259)